# How does WordPress internal url rewrite work?

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

Wordpress's htaccess file (generally) looks like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /wordpress/  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]  
</IfModule>
```

Using this Rewrite rule, Apache redirects not found URLs to `index.php`. And then PHP processes the URL and gives us the relevant data. I have read this at many places.

But actually how does PHP redirect? I would like to understand the technique behind this redirect.

I mean is it using PHP `header()` function? Or some other technique?

Comment: Check `/wp-includes/rewrite.php` script, [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite) class and [Rewrite_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) to have an idea.

Comment: I have checked the file couple times, but it's quite lengthy file. So i thought it would be easier to ask to some expert. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

What the rules mean in plain english:

1. If the url is `/wordpress/index.php`, stop processing rules.
2. If the requested non-empty url is not a file or a directory, hand the request over to `/wordpress/index.php` and stop processing rules.

Internally, WP then considers the original url, matches it against known route patterns using regular expression, and sets the request type and parameters accordingly.

Comment: I would also like to know who handles(processes) the result generated by WordPress rewrite and where are these route patterns stored? Thanks in advance.

Comment: WP processes it itself and stores the "compiled" result as an option (try `var_dump(get_option('rewrite_rules'));` for quick retrieval later on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry i cant vote up because i dont have enough reputation. :-D

Answer (score 1):

wordpress doesn't redirect the request. index.php serves the content base on the original request_uri.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that redirection is not used. Because if redirection is used, URL wont remain the same after rewriting.

Comment: One more question, after it has decided the exact path like "index.php?catagory_name=xx&feed=xx" , how does it decides which page from theme to load?